# Control legend in ggplotly when using subplot

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

I use the R `plotly` package and the functions `ggplotly` and `subplot` to create an interactive plot consisting of multiple individually interactive `ggplot2` plots. Some of the plots share the same grouping variables.

```
col <- factor(rep(c(1, 2), 5))
fill <- factor(c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)))
x1 <- x2 <- y1 <- y2 <- 1:10
x3 <- y3 <- 11:20
d1 <- dplyr::tibble(x1 = x1, y1 = y1, col = col)
d2 <- dplyr::tibble(x2 = x2, y2 = y2, col = col, fill = fill)
d3 <- dplyr::tibble(x3 = x3, y3 = y3, col = col)

g1 <- 
  ggplot2::ggplot(d1) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes(x = x1, y = y1, col = col))

g2 <- 
  ggplot2::ggplot(d2) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes(x = x2, y = y2, col = col, fill = fill)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c("red","green")) 

g3 <- 
  ggplot2::ggplot(d3) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes(x = x3, y = y3, col = col))

plotly::subplot(plotly::ggplotly(g1), plotly::ggplotly(g2), plotly::ggplotly(g3))
```

[image]

1) How can I remove the duplicated "col" labels in the interactive `plotly` legend?

2) How can I remove the legend for "fill", but keep the legend for "col"?

---

EDIT: I know about the following "dirty" solution, which is to manually disable the legend:

```
t <- 
plotly::subplot(plotly::ggplotly(g1), plotly::ggplotly(g2), plotly::ggplotly(g3))

t$x$data[[1]]$showlegend <- FALSE
t$x$data[[2]]$showlegend <- FALSE
t$x$data[[3]]$showlegend <- FALSE
t$x$data[[4]]$showlegend <- FALSE
```

However, this requires me to know the positions of the list elements in advance, which is why I am looking for a more general solution.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I ended up using the "dirty" solution.

Comment: Hi, did anyone found a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to manually remove the unwanted legends is to use `style()`.  In your example, `lt <- t %>% style(t, showlegend = FALSE, traces = 3:n)`, where `n<-8` is defined before, will suppress the unwanted legends.